# Which config for nginx serving angularjs app in a subdirectory

Tags: angularjs, nginx

I want to serve an angular.js using html5mode app in a subdirectory.

I used this config found here https://gist.github.com/cjus/b46a243ba610661a7efb.

```
  location /adm/ { # trailing slash here
        alias share/nginx/html/dev2/; # and here as well

        expires -1;
        add_header Pragma "no-cache";
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";

        try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ $uri/ /adm/index.html =404; # /adm/index.html and not /index.html
    }
```

I'm always forwarded to the home directory. For example when i go to /adm/dashboard i'm redirected to /

Comment: Please post your entire config